# Many textareas don't work as they should - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two `textarea` elements that need to be resized as person types in them( in Y-axis ). I have written code that resizes the `textarea` successfully, but that code doesn't work with many `textareas` that are on the page.

Code for the working code -  one textarea

Now, if You run this code, it would work perfectly fine, as you type or go to new line, the box will respond to that. It will be stretched.

Can someone explain why this code doesn't work (even better, show me what I need to do to make it work) for two or more textareas? For something like this:

```js
 $(document)
    .one('focus.autoExpand', 'textarea.autoExpand', function(){
        var savedValue = this.value;
        this.value = '';
        this.baseScrollHeight = this.scrollHeight;
        this.value = savedValue;
    })
    .on('input.autoExpand', 'textarea.autoExpand', function(){
        var minRows = this.getAttribute('data-min-rows')|0, rows;
        this.rows = minRows;
        rows = Math.ceil((this.scrollHeight - this.baseScrollHeight) / 16);
        this.rows = minRows + rows;
    });
```

```css
    /* JUST FOR THIS DEMO */
    html, body {
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    body {
      background: #4A90E2;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
    }

    textarea {
      display: block;
      box-sizing: padding-box;
      overflow: hidden;
      padding: 10px;
      width: 250px;
      font-size: 14px;
      margin: 50px auto;
      border-radius: 6px;
      box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      border: 0;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class='autoExpand' rows='3' 
  data-min-rows='3' placeholder='Auto-Expanding Textarea'></textarea>
<textarea class='autoExpand' rows='3' 
  data-min-rows='3' placeholder='Auto-Expanding Textarea'></textarea>
```

Comment: The problem is simply a typo; replacing your `.one()` with `.on()` solves the issue.

Comment: Just as @ObsidianAge said use On, not One https://jsfiddle.net/cdga7hkb/

Comment: I'm curious if the `one` was not a typo, and instead an attempt to only do the initialization once.  Which with a single element was a valid approach.

Comment: @bhmahler Yes, but that breaks the code in the long run. If you go and type something in texarea1, and type in textarea2 after, then if you go and edit something in textarea1 again, it collapses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changed the `one` to `on`, however added logic so that it knows not to re-initialize the same element multiple times.

```js
$(document)
  .on('focus.autoExpand', 'textarea.autoExpand', function() {
    if (!this.getAttribute('data-initialized')){
      this.setAttribute('data-initialized', 'true');
      var savedValue = this.value;
      this.value = '';
      this.baseScrollHeight = this.scrollHeight;
      this.value = savedValue;
    }
  })
  .on('input.autoExpand', 'textarea.autoExpand', function() {
    var minRows = this.getAttribute('data-min-rows') | 0,
      rows;
    this.rows = minRows;
    rows = Math.ceil((this.scrollHeight - this.baseScrollHeight) / 16);
    this.rows = minRows + rows;
  });
```

Comment: Beat me by 30 secs ;)

Comment: I missed that part of re-initialization. Crossed my mind when it changed its size, but didn't persist in adjusting it.

Answer (score 1):

I modifed your code to use on and track whether or not the box had been initialized using a data attribute. It will only process the focus code if it has not already been initialized and the data attribute set

```
$(document)
.on('focus.autoExpand', 'textarea.autoExpand', function(){
    if(!$(this).data('initialized')){
      var savedValue = this.value;
      this.value = '';
      this.baseScrollHeight = this.scrollHeight;
      this.value = savedValue;
      $(this).data('initialized', true);
    }
})
.on('input.autoExpand', 'textarea.autoExpand', function(){
    var minRows = this.getAttribute('data-min-rows')|0, rows;
    this.rows = minRows;
    rows = Math.ceil((this.scrollHeight - this.baseScrollHeight) / 16);
    this.rows = minRows + rows;
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cdga7hkb/1/

Comment: I told in the comment section above, I missed that part of re-initialization. Great job on the speed!